# What "interactive components" can be used in an amp-story?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

It's not clear from the Interactive Components section in the documentation. https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-story/#interactive-components.

I'm trying to create a poll within an amp-story, but doesn't seem to be a clear path to it. I tried to hack it with amp-consent, but that's not really working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a poll, you'd need `amp-form` component which you can't use for `amp-stories`
[See this list of which components are allowed.](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/?format=stories)

Note that stories are meant to deliver content in an immersive way, not to necessary run polls or collect info.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm finding too! Hopefully there's some simple interactivity added in the future.

Comment: @tarunsachdeva my pleasure!

Comment: Polls are hopefully coming soon!  Once we have some information documented on GitHub, I can link it here

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the amp sepcification reqwire a user interaction to trigger an script. event listener like window load or document completet are not allowed on a amp html page.